# Check if User exist in mysql database

Tags: javascript, sql

I have created a working POST request but Would like to know how I can create it so that I am able to check if the same username exist as I am not sure how I can start. I have posted 2 sets of code below, a controller and model set, Thanks a lot !

File 1

```
//POST
app.post('/users', function(req,res){
    var username = req.body.username;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var contact = req.body.contact;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var type = req.body.type;
    var profile_pic_url = req.body.profile_pic_url;

    usersDB.Insertuser(username,email,contact,password,type,profile_pic_url,function(err,result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
            res.type('json');
            res.statusCode=500;
            res.send(`{"Result":"Internal Error"}`);

        } else{
            res.type("json");
            res.statusCode=201;
            //res.send(result);
            console.log(result);
            res.send(`{"Affected Rows":"${result.affectedRows}"}`);
        }

    });
});
```

File 2

```
// Insert name,course, code
    Insertuser:function(username , email, contact, password, type,profile_pic_url,callback){
 
        var dbConn=db.getConnection();
 
        // connects to the mysql database (contains an asyn function that returns a callback)
        dbConn.connect(function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                return callback(err,null);
 
            }else{
                var sql="insert into users(username,email,contact,password,type,profile_pic_url) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                dbConn.query(sql,[username , email, contact, password, type,profile_pic_url],function(err,result){
                    
                    dbConn.end();
                    // if(err){
                    //     console.log(err);
                    // }
 
                    return callback(err,result);
                });
 
            }
 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your Insertuser function.

```
Insertuser:function(username , email, contact, password, type,profile_pic_url,callback){

    var dbConn=db.getConnection();

    // connects to the mysql database (contains an asyn function that returns a callback)
    dbConn.connect(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return callback(err,null);

        }else{
            // Query for get all rows from users table where username = entered username
            var checkSql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?';
            
            dbConn.query(checkSql, [username], function(err, result) {
                
                if(err) {
                    return callback(err,null);
                
                }else {
                    // Checking if the result length is more than 0.
                     if(result.length > 0) {
                         return callback('Username already exist', null);
                     }else {
                         
                         var sql="insert into users(username,email,contact,password,type,profile_pic_url) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                        dbConn.query(sql,[username , email, contact, password, type,profile_pic_url],function(err,result){
                            
                            if(err)
                                return callback(err, null);
                            }
                                
                            dbConn.end();
         
                            return callback(err,result);
                        });
                     }
                    
                }
                
            })
            
          

        }

    });
```

Comment: Thank You this helped a lot ! , Understand it much better after reading through